# MVC Architecture without modules

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web

Is that wrong if i use MVC architecture without separate modules? I'm only using three folders for entire application.

- view - all the interface files.
- controller - logics, algorithms..etc
- model - database handlers, classes...etc

or do i need to use separate modules?

example:

- employee: view,model,controller
- payments: view,model,controller
- loan: view,model,controller
- products: view,model,controller

I'm using PHP. Please help me.

Comment: A good application is not based on how many folders do you have

Comment: The model typically contains many sub folders/modules/parts, depending on what exactly your application does and needs. There's no one rule. The only thing that MVC is about is about the proper separation between the model (everything your core app does), its views and the glue that makes both work (the controller).

Comment: controller is **not** for logic and model is **not** a db abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think there is a standard for this, meaning this totally depends on you.
here is what i use:

```
+application
   +controller
     -a.php
     -b.php
     -c.php
   +model
     -aModel.php
   +view
      -a.phtml
      -b.phtml
      -c.phtml
 +public
      +js
      +css
```

etc..

my aim is seperating layers: html and php